# I am trying to display a set of values from a database table.I got the values but cant display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
const url ="http://localhost:80/form/api/request.php"
class User extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            user:[]
        }
    }
    handle(){
        axios.get(url)
        .then(result=>{
            this.setState({user:result.data})
            console.log(result.data);
        });
    }
    render(){
        let {user}=this.state.user;
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={e=>this.handle(e)}>Get</button>
                {
                user && user.map(users=>{
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <h3>name:{users}</h3>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
                
    }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default User;
```

1.Here on clicking the button i get the values on the console

2.But that's all the map() doesnot show any values

3. The 'get' returns only a single column values

Comment: what is the result of console.log(result.data); ?

Comment: its  this:{"lname":"a"}{"lname":"AM"} these are the values in the tabl

Comment: try   <h3>name:{users.lname}</h3>

Comment: no its not working

Answer (score -1):

In the code snippet you have shared destructuring of state object is not correct. You need to use `let {user} = this.state`. Since the user was undefined it was not showing any values.

Comment: i tried that but the error:Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): user.map is not a function occurs when i execute it

Comment: What is the type of value in `result.data` ? If it is an array `.map()` will work. I think you are not receiving an array. can you check that ?

Comment: you are right, the query result is not an array.How do i change that

Comment: {"lname":"a"}{"lname":"AM"} these are the present values of result.data .I used fetch_assoc in php, so what should i use instead.